# How to include folders, created within the Project, in the output directories?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm making an internal tool to more easily track files associated with bug / feature requests. Essentially, it's just a series of nested `TabControl` controls.

There'll be a top level `TabControl tcProjects` that will contain N number of `TabPage` controls.

These project `TabPage` controls will each contain another `TabControl tcActiveArchived` which will just contain two `TabPage` controls: one for active issues currently being worked on / not yet deployed, and then an archived `TabPage` for issues that have been deployed / tested.

Finally, the active / archived `TabPage` controls will contain yet another `TabControl tcActive` / `TabControl tcArchived` with N number of `TabPage` controls for each individual item.

So ultimately, it'll look like this:

[image]

Except their will be one higher, top-level `TabControl` for the projects than what is shown in that screenshot.

Basically it's just a glorified text file manager. It reads / writes the contents of each numbered tab to a text file in a directory structure that matches the `TabControl` / `TabPage` structure.

What I'm doing is just adding a "base" folder called `Projects` to my project in the Solution Explorer pane in Visual Studio. Then I added a random junk file I don't care about to that folder so that way when I build the project that folder actually gets created in bin/Debug, and I've been writing the text files to that folder there. So basically it'd be something like this:

> myVSproject/bin/debug/Projects/ProjectNumeroUno/Active/13559.txt
>   myVSproject/bin/debug/Projects/ProjectNumeroUno/Active/13612.txt
>   myVSproject/bin/debug/Projects/ProjectNumeroUno/Archived/13615.txt

I'd like to do something a little more "legitimate" this time as I'm improving the software. I had read in other SO questions on this topic that suggest you add a Setup project which will create the installer for the application and from there you can dictate which folders get added to the installation but this is a far less than ideal situation as we aren't really installing the software on our machines but rather just running the exe that VS dumps out when you build your solution. This doesn't require installation and avoids some of the bureaucratic tape at the office.

So, how can I create an empty, "base level" `Projects` folder at compile time?

Comment: Does it need to be compile time? Could itbe, for example, on first launch of the application? You could pull one of the [SpecialFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)s and create a new Projects folder there, relative to the user's system (`SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` ro `SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`, for example).

Comment: I might be able to work with that. I was hoping to avoid adding code to the application to handle this- at that point it'd be not much different than `if (!Directory.Exists(currentDir + "../Projects")) Directory.Create(...)` (or something to that effect) but it does feel "less hacky", at least.

Comment: Unfortunately with a standalone executable you're kind of stuck with what you can do on first launch, since you don't want an installer. Have you thought about a ClickOnce deployment?

Comment: One other idea: Create a self-extracting zip package that can run a script after extraction: http://superuser.com/a/42792/13980. Stuff your .exe and dependencies and a short batch file in there that creates the "Project" folder.

Comment: Why not use a project management tool? TFS (as one example) has exactly this kind of functionality built right in.